# Tracing the line of motion of a point in graphics

Tags: graphics, engineering, mechanism

I'm a beginner in mathematica. I'm making a nb that calculates the output angle of a fourbar mechanism based on the input angle. So the input is the length of the four linkages and the input angle of the crank and the output is the angle of rocker.

I've already made my code and it works well. I plot it in a graphics as well. Now I want to trace the point B which is the TIP of the coupler. I want to trace the path of motion of this point to plot the output curve.

```
outputAngle[r1_, r2_, r3_, 
  r4_, ϕ_] := (* r1 is the crank; r2 is the coupler; r3 is the \
rocker; r4 is the link between oA and oB; ϕ is the input angle \
of the crank; This function calculates the output angle of the \
rocker.*)
 {a1 = N[Sin[ϕ Degree]],
  b1 = N[r4/r1 + Cos[ϕ Degree]],
  c1 = N[r4/r3 Cos[ϕ Degree] + 
     N[(r1^2 - r2^2 + r3^2 + r4^2)/(2 r1 r2)]],
  ψ = 
   2 ArcTan[N[(a1 + √(a1^2 + b1^2 - c1^2))/(b1 + c1)]]/ 
     Degree,(*Output Angle Calculated by Equation from the refrence*)

    a2 = N[AngleVector[{r1, ϕ Degree}]],(*point A Starting from \
origin*)

  b2 = N[AngleVector[{-r4, 
      0}, {r3, ψ  Degree}]],(*Point B Starting from Ob*)

  N[AngleVector[{-r4, 0}]],(*Point oB*)

  d = √((b2[[1]] - a2[[1]])^2 + (b2[[2]] - 
        a2[[2]])^2) (*distance between A & B This is just to confirm \
that a2's length is constant*)
  }

Slider[Dynamic[t], {0, 720, 1}]

Dynamic[
 m = outputAngle[2, 8, 6, 6, 
   t]  (*This is the passing of values to the main function that \
calculates the output angle*)
 ]

Dynamic[ (*This is the drawing of the four bar linkage out put*)

 Graphics[{
   Line[{{0, 0}, m[[5]]}],
   Line[{m[[5]], m[[6]]}],
   Line[{m[[7]], m[[6]]}],
   Line[{{0, 0}, m[[7]]}],
   Locator[m[[6]]]
   }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-9, 6}, {-3, 8}}]
 ]
```

That is my code. I made sure to comment all the inputs so it makes sense. I need to trace the point B or m[[6]] in the graphics area. Any help?

[image: The graphics output]

Comment: Your `outputAngle` function already gives you the coordinates of that path, so would it be acceptable to add a pre-calculated path to your plot, i.e. something like `Line@Table[outputAngle[2, 8, 6, 6, t][[6]], {t, 0, 360, 1}]` inside the `Dynamic[Graphics[...]]` that produces your main output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought I would show you what I meant in my comment, together with the end product of my proposed modification, so you can decide if that's acceptable for your application. I am using all your definitions from the original questions.

I calculated the `path` as a `Line` object generated from a series of points calculated by your outputAngle function over the full range of motion (i.e. one full turn of the crank). Here I am assuming that your `t` represents the crank angular position in degrees, so its full range is $(0, 360)$.

I then added path inside your `Graphics` expression as the first object, so it sits below the locator and other lines and doesn't obscure them.

Finally, I slightly enlarged your explicit `PlotRange` to add some space to the left of the plot, otherwise the path line went right up against the `Graphics` bounding box. This is just aesthetics though; it would work with your original `PlotRange` just as well.

```
path = Line@Table[outputAngle[2, 8, 6, 6, t][[6]], {t, 0, 360, 1}];

Dynamic[
 Graphics[{
   (* Here is the traced path *)
   {Red, Thick, Dashed, path},
   (* These are your original linkages *)
   Line[{{0, 0}, m[[5]]}],
   Line[{m[[5]], m[[6]]}],
   Line[{m[[7]], m[[6]]}],
   Line[{{0, 0}, m[[7]]}],
   Locator[m[[6]]]
   },
  Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-9.5, 6}, {-3, 8}}
  ]
]
```

[image: animated path]

---

### Update:

You mentioned that you would like to make the definitions for the current configuration of the linkages in one place. One way to achieve that is by modifying your definition of `outputAngle` to be a pure function which takes only the configuration parameters, and output expressions for angles and positions still as a function of an undefined variable (look up `#`, `Slot` in the docs).

You can then apply this pure function to the `t` variable when you need the numerical values.

While I was at it, I also modified the `Line` code in your `Dynamic[Graphics[...]]` to showcase the use of multiple points to generate a series of connected segments with a single `Line` expression.

Here is the modified code:

```
Clear[outputAngle, currentConfiguration]

outputAngle[r1_, r2_, r3_, r4_] =
  {
    a1 = N[Sin[# Degree]], b1 = N[r4/r1 + Cos[# Degree]],
    c1 = N[r4/r3 Cos[# Degree] + N[(r1^2 - r2^2 + r3^2 + r4^2)/(2 r1 r2)]],
    ψ = 2 ArcTan[N[(a1 + Sqrt[a1^2 + b1^2 - c1^2])/(b1 + c1)]]/Degree,
    a2 = N[AngleVector[{r1, # Degree}]],
    b2 = N[AngleVector[{-r4, 0}, {r3, ψ Degree}]],
    N[AngleVector[{-r4, 0}]],
    d = Sqrt[(b2[[1]] - a2[[1]])^2 + (b2[[2]] - a2[[2]])^2]
    } &;

(* Here is the one place where you set the configuration of your linkage *)
currentConfiguration = outputAngle[2, 8, 6, 6];

(* Now calculate the full path of the rocker *)
path = Line@Table[currentConfiguration[t][[6]], {t, 0, 360, 1}];

Slider[Dynamic[t], {0, 720, 1}]
Dynamic[m = currentConfiguration[t]]

Dynamic[Graphics[{
   (* The path of the rocker *)
   {Red, Dashed, path},
   (* The linkages *)
   Line[{{0, 0}, m[[5]], m[[6]], m[[7]], {0, 0}}],
   Locator[m[[6]]]},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-9.5, 6}, {-3, 8}}
]]
```

Comment: PERFECT answer.. This is my first encounter with the function Table. Seems very interesting. can you please tell me more about why did you use Line@Table? What does this expression mean?

Comment: Here are the [docs for Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html). Super-useful function, I recommend you familiarize yourself with it! For your second point, in general `f@g` is a shortcut form of `f[g]`, so `Line@Table[...]` is just a shortcut for `Line[ Table[...] ]`. I find it very useful for functions that take a single argument, so you don't have to enclose that argument in square brackets, and end up chasing brackets around :-). Also, `Line` can take multiple points as input, not just two; it will then produce a series of segments connecting those points.

Comment: Let me also point you towards this FAQ: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/27951), and more in general at all the answers in that thread. It can make for interesting reading!

Comment: AWESOME! I will dig into that in more details. I also noticed you ended your pat definition with a ;  as i saw that makes the definition evaluate but doesn't not show the output. Is that accurate?

Comment: Last question any suggestion how to make the passing of argument to path better? I mean now I have to change the input twice? once in m variable and later in path.... the exp passed to table has to include the variable you want to change! so i tried m[[6]] but it won't work! other approach maybe?

Comment: I proposed a changed version of your code that allows you to change the configuration in one place only. Also, you are correct about the fact that `;` suppresses output. That is a commonly exploited side-effect of `;`. For a better treatment of its true meaning, please see: [Understand that semicolon (;) is not a delimiter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/27951) in the Common Pitfalls series.

Comment: i'm reading about the pure functions now. your implementation is quite nice. from what you said a pure function takes expressions and returns expressions. I think the documentation fails to describe that properly. any reading about the difference between normal function and a pure on in details? why didn't we use SetDelayedn := in the function definition? it would make more sense to use it there